# Laravel 4 Connect to EC2 MySQL from remote domain

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

Not sure if what I am attempting to do is possible or not. I just launched my very first EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04 and successfully installed Laravel 4. I have the database working just fine on the EC2 instance and I am able to connect to it with MySQL Workbench on my local machine using a `.pem` SSH key.

I will be using EC2 to handle certain aspects of a product that I am developing to ensure improved reliability - client side users will be interacting with this primarily through CURL. I want to be able to have my non-EC2 website, also running Laravel 4, use the MySQL database that I set up on my EC2 instance.

I tried changing my `app/config/database.php` file to include the EC2 instance IP address and MySQL credentials, when Laravel attempts to connect it returns a timeout error.

I modified my.cfn and commented out `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, I do not seem to have the `skip-network` that I have seen mentioned. Still no joy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I'm almost there. I followed steps to modify the instance's MySQL settings to allow for wildcard access to a MySQL user I created, now I can connect from my local machine but still not from my VPS. Contact support, suspect this is due to a firewall issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

I changed bind-address to 0.0.0.0, created a new MySQL user - `'user'@'%'`, and had my host whitelist the IP. Done!

Answer (score 0):

In side MySQL (PhpMyAdmin if you installed it) -> Users overview -> Edit your user with Host is

```
%
```

That is mean, you can connect to MySQL in anywhere with command

```
mysql_connect($IpOfYourHost, $UserAbove, $Password)
```

Maybe this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I did this from the command line.. I am able to connect from my computer now, still not from the other server. Working with support.. hopefully it's in their hands now